# Having trouble with validation: infinite loop occurs even though the logic seems fine

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am working on this 'restaurant' program, that takes two inputs: the bill amount and a satisfactionlevel from 1 to 3. I have tried to validate each output using the hasNextDouble(), but for some reason when i run the program the else statement in the first if statement runs infinitly. Can someone please take a look at this?

```
package tips;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tips {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Ask for the diners’ satisfaction level using these ratings: 
    1 = Totally satisfied, 2 = Satisfied, 3 = Dissatisfied.
    If the diner is totally satisfied, calculate a 20 percent tip.
    If the diner is satisfied, calculate a 15 percent tip.
    If the diner is dissatisfied, calculate a 10 percent tip.
    Report the satisfaction level and tip in dollars and cents.*/

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean isDouble = false;
    boolean isInt = false;

    TipsCalculator tips = new TipsCalculator();

    while (!isDouble && !isInt) {
          System.out.print("Please enter the bill amount: ");
          //Checks if the input is a double.
          if(in.hasNextDouble()) {
              tips.setBill(in.nextDouble());
              isDouble = true;
          } else {
              System.out.println("The value entered is not a valid amount.");
              continue;
          }

          System.out.println("Please enter your satisfaction level: \n1 = Totally Satisfied.\n2 = Satisfied.\n3 = Dissatisfied.");
          //Checks if the input is an integer.
          if(in.hasNextInt()) {
              tips.setSatisfactionLevel(in.nextInt());
              isInt = true;
              //Prints different outputs depending on the satisfaction level.
              if (tips.getSatisfactionLevel() == 1) {
                  System.out.println("You are totally satisfied! :-)" + 
                          ". \n" + 
                          "Your tip amount is: " + 
                          tips.calculateTips());
              } else if (tips.getSatisfactionLevel() == 2){
                  System.out.println("You are satisfied! :-)" + 
                          ". \n" + 
                          "Your tip amount is: " + 
                          tips.calculateTips());
              } else if (tips.getSatisfactionLevel() == 3) {
                  System.out.println("You are dissatisfied! :-(" + 
                          ". \n" + 
                          "Your tip amount is: " + 
                          tips.calculateTips());
              } else {
                  //Error if the level is not from 1 to 3.
                  System.out.println("The value entered is not between 1 and 3");
              }
          } else {
              System.out.println("The value entered is not between 1 and 3");
              continue;
          }
    } in.close();

}

}
```

Comment: Oh and the error occurs when I enter a decimal number like: 39.4

Comment: if you are not in the US, you may need to set the locale in.useLocale(Locale.US);

Comment: If I enter 39 it works fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read input as double and int. read it as Strings and then parse it to Double or Integer in your code. Use method valueOf(String) in classes Integer and Double. to parse your Strings

Comment: It is just a better practice to allow user to give you an input and parse and validate it yourself. So you read an input as raw data and only then validate it.

Answer (score 2):

`isDoubl` & `isInt` both are false so `!isDouble && !isInt` will be always true. This is the root cause behind infinite loop

Comment: That's makes no sense - ! is the not operator so !isDouble is true if isDouble is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for infinite loop is:
**hasNextDouble** method in **Scanner** class calls **hasNext** method internally.
It has written like this

```
public boolean hasNext(Pattern pattern) {
        ensureOpen();
        if (pattern == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        hasNextPattern = null;
        saveState();

        while (true) {
            if (getCompleteTokenInBuffer(pattern) != null) {
                matchValid = true;
                cacheResult();
                return revertState(true);
            }
            if (needInput)
                readInput();
            else
                return revertState(false);
        }
    }
```

In the above method, **getCompleteTokenInBuffer** method call is the real culprit. This **getCompleteTokenInBuffer** can return following 3 possibilities

```
/*
 * 1. valid string means it was found
 * 2. null with needInput=false means we won't ever find it
 * 3. null with needInput=true means try again after readInput
 */
```

In **hasNext** mthod, whenever we first enter non double value, we will be able to read data and **getCompleteTokenInBuffer** returns null and will also set **needInput=false** for the first time. But, for the second time, **hasNext** method will return with value **false** as **needInput=false** condition will be true.

This **needInput = false** condition will remain true for the subsequent **hasNextDouble** method call. Because of this we were not able to read any data and this was causing infinite loop.